# Calculate input of textbox and update another without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my UI - http://puu.sh/bbx5G/33953b74ea.png

I want to calculate marks of 5 papers -> input in 1st textbox and update 2nd textbox (with equivalent grade) without reload of page. That means, as I am typing, the grade textbox should be updated. I tried to run a for loop and iterate through the 5 IDs of **marks** and **grades** after hitting a submit button but it didn't seem to work. So firstly I need to make this work, and after that, I want something which will instantly updated the **grades** field while i type the marks.
My HTML form having tables:

```
<td><input type="text" id="pm1" onkeypress="validate(event)" onchange="" maxlength=3/> = 
<input type="text" id="pg1" onkeypress="return inputLimiter(event)" maxlength=1/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="pm2" onkeypress="validate(event)" maxlength=3/> = 
<input type="text" id="pg2" onkeypress="return inputLimiter(event)" maxlength=1/></td>
..... upto pm5 and pg5
```

My Javascript:

```
function calculate_g(){
var i = 1;
var m = 0.0;
var p = 0.0;
var g = '';
for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        m = document.getElementById("pm"+i).value;
        p = (m / 80.00) * 100.00;       
        if(p >= 45.00 && p <= 49.99) { g = 'P'; }
        if(p >= 50.00 && p <= 54.99) { g = 'E'; }
        if(p >= 55.00 && p <= 59.99) { g = 'D'; }
        if(p >= 60.00 && p <= 69.99) { g = 'C'; }
        if(p >= 70.00 && p <= 74.99) { g = 'B'; }
        if(p >= 75.00 && p <= 79.99) { g = 'A'; }
        if(p >= 80.00) { g = 'O'; }
        document.getElementById("pg"+i).value = g;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `.value` at `m = document.getElementById("pm"+i)`

Comment: I tried that too. It didn't work. This code and other trials and errors been done already.

Comment: Try this.  m = $("[id$=pm" + i + "]").val();

Comment: How are you calling calculate_g ?

Comment: @Ranjith, it didn't seem to work.
@ Callebe, I am calling it in this way: <form onsubmit="calculate_g()">

Comment: Would you be able to step through the code? You could try to put some alerts inside that function to verify whether it's being called or not. You could try blur event to calculate grades. Here is the example. $("[Id^=pm]").blur(function () {
        calculate_g();
    });

Comment: Yes. I tried to print the value of **g** in an alert box, it did give my 5 alerts. But the value didn't print there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the fields without a page reload, you can structure your code like so, and expand it as needed for more inputs.  You can do the validation on form submit or on keyup, whichever is easier for you:

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/fesjejnp/

```
<table>
<tr><td>
        ESE1<input type="text" id="pm1" onkeyup="calc()" maxlength=3/> = 
        PR1<input type="text" id="pg1" maxlength=1/ class="pipe" readonly>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        ESE2<input type="text" id="pm2" onkeyup="calc()" maxlength=3/> = 
        PR2<input type="text" id="pg2" maxlength=1/ class="pipe" readonly></td></tr>
</table>

<script>

function calc() {
    var m;
    var p = 0.0;
    var g = '';

    for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
      m = document.getElementById("pm" + i).value;      
      g = getGrade(p,m);
      document.getElementById("pg" + i).value = g;
    }
}

function getGrade(p,m) {
    var g;
    p = (m / 80.00) * 100.00;       
    if(p >= 45.00 && p <= 49.99) { g = 'P'; }
    else if(p >= 50.00 && p <= 54.99) { g = 'E'; }
    else if(p >= 55.00 && p <= 59.99) { g = 'D'; }
    else if(p >= 60.00 && p <= 69.99) { g = 'C'; }
    else if(p >= 70.00 && p <= 74.99) { g = 'B'; }
    else if(p >= 75.00 && p <= 79.99) { g = 'A'; }
    else if(p >= 80.00) { g = 'O'; }
    else { g = 'X'; }
    return g;
}
</script>
```

Comment: No prob, I cleaned up the code a little bit as well.  You might want to use HTML5 to help validate your inputs if you plan on using numbers only.

Comment: That's fine. I think I might get rid of the javascrpit for validations now.

Comment: You can add the following attributes and it'll do HTML validation for you (number only, min-max range).  Note, you'll need to add the onchange to handle the spinner (up/down arrow) as well. 
Updated the fiddle with HTML validation: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/fesjejnp/3/)
             

ESE1<input type="number" id="pm1" onkeyup="calc()" onchange="calc()" maxlength=3 min="0" max="100"/>

Comment: Updated the fiddle with HTML validation: 
[http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/fesjejnp/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/fesjejnp/3/)

Comment: Okay, I have one doubt. If I am allowing input of the grade, i.e the one which gets calculated after feeding the marks; then can I do something such that a user can add his grade, in case he doesn't know his marks? Cause that might be necessary. If I try that right now, it gets set to 'F' which was set in else condition, when the marks are empty.

Comment: User input is definitely possible, however, it might require additional planning in terms of requirements.  Would the marks get updated or the input disabled if a user adds his own grade?  Another option may be to add a separate input for user input or comments, that would be separate from your calculations.

Comment: I figured a way out. Thanks for the concern. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this it will solve all requirements

JSFIDDLE Link: http://jsfiddle.net/8fkkqvt8/
`

```
<table border="2">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="pm1" onkeyup="calculate_g()" onchange="" maxlength=3/> = 
    <input type="text" id="pg1" disabled="disabled"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="pm2" onkeypress="validate(event)" maxlength=3/> = 
    <input type="text" id="pg2" onkeypress="return inputLimiter(event)" maxlength=1/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>

function calculate_g(){
    var i = 1;
    var m = 0.0;
    var p = 0.0;
    var g = '';
    for(i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
        m = document.getElementById("pm"+i).value;      
        p = (m / 80.00) * 100.00;           
        if(p >= 45.00 && p <= 49.99) { g = 'P'; }
        if(p >= 50.00 && p <= 54.99) { g = 'E'; }
        if(p >= 55.00 && p <= 59.99) { g = 'D'; }
        if(p >= 60.00 && p <= 69.99) { g = 'C'; }
        if(p >= 70.00 && p <= 74.99) { g = 'B'; }
        if(p >= 75.00 && p <= 79.99) { g = 'A'; }
        if(p >= 80.00) { g = 'O'; }     
        document.getElementById("pg"+i).value = g;
    }

}
</script>
```

`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that the OP was asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <b>
           ESE1 
        </b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="grade" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>
           = PR1 
        </b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="letter" size="5" maxlength="5" value="X" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <b>
            ESE2
        </b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="grade" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>
            = PR2
        </b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="letter" size="5" maxlength="5" value="X" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <b>
            ESE3
        </b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="grade" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>
            = PR3
        </b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="letter" size="5" maxlength="5" value="X" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <b>
            ESE4
        </b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="grade" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>
            = PR4
        </b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="letter" size="5" maxlength="5" value="X" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <b>
            ESE5
        </b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="grade" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>
            = PR5 
        </b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="letter" size="5" maxlength="5" value="X" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Use jQuery `.each` function

$(function() {

```
var letter = (e) => (e >= 80) ? 'O' :
                    (e >= 75) ? 'A' :
                    (e >= 70) ? 'B' :
                    (e >= 60) ? 'C' :
                    (e >= 55) ? 'D' :
                    (e >= 50) ? 'E' : 
                    (e >= 45) ? 'P' : 'X';

$('.grade').keyup(function(e) {
    $('.grade').each(function(index) {
        var val = parseFloat($('.grade:eq(' + index + ')').val()) * 1.25 || 0;
        $('.letter:eq(' + index + ')').val(letter(val));
    });
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/0mjsgpc3/7/